# How to call server-side code from JavaScript in a provider-hosted SharePoint App?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, sharepoint, single-page-application

I'm working on a provider-hosted App for SharePoint and I used the "Hot Towel Angular" package from nuget to create a SPA. As far as I know one major benefit of having a provider-hosted app is the ability to execute server-side code. My question is: How do I do that in a SPA?

This is my attempt:
In the index.cshtml

```
@Html.ActionLink("RunWithElevatedPrivileges", "RunWithElevatedPrivileges", "Employee")
```

In the EmployeeController.cs

```
        public ActionResult RunWithElevatedPrivileges()
    {
        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

        //using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost())
        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateAppOnlyClientContextForSPHost())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                clientContext.Load(web);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyList3");
                ListItemCreationInformation info = new ListItemCreationInformation();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item = list.AddItem(info);
                item["Title"] = "Created from CSOM";

                item.Update();
                clientContext.Load(item);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }

        return View("ItemCreated");
    }
```

Is there a decent solution to just execute the code from JavaScript without changing the view? I want to code my solution with Angular and JavaScript and only call the C#-Code when necessary.